# DocuSign: SIGNATURE_PROVIDER_INVALID_FOR_NONSBS

Tags: docusignapi, unqork

I'm trying to integrate Docusign with an Unqork app. I am trying to place the sample request that was given in createEnvelope REST API for SBS digital signature, with an embedded signing ceremony.

While trying to invoke the API, got this error:

```
executionError: {type: "integratorError",…}
code: 412
component: "pluginCreateEnvelope"
message: {,…}
executionError: {type: "integratorError", url: "http://localhost:43235/fbu/uapi/services/Docusign-Sandbox/execute",…}
code: 400
component: "pluginCreateEnvelope"
message: {errorCode: "SIGNATURE_PROVIDER_INVALID_FOR_NONSBS",…}
errorCode: "SIGNATURE_PROVIDER_INVALID_FOR_NONSBS"
message: "Signature providers are not valid for this recipient. Standards Based Signatures must be enabled for the sending account. Envelope is not configured for support of recipient signing providers"
type: "integratorError"
url: "http://localhost:43235/fbu/uapi/services/Docusign-Sandbox/execute"
type: "integratorError"
url: "http://localhost:43235/fbu/uapi/modules/620cbdc72b8a8801b9b67967/execute"
```

Can someone help how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you have SBS (digital signature) enabled for the developer account you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Docusign demo accounts don't have SBS enabled by default. To fix your error you have to get in contact with your account team/sales team so they can add this to your account.

As an alternative you can remove "recipientSignatureProviders" from your envelopes in the demo environment and only use it with your production account.